# Why does this grep for a string in all sub directories not work?

Tags: command-line, directory, grep

This is the command that I am trying to run.

```
grep -r "printf" *.c
```

I am trying to get all the printf lines from all `.c` files present in my cwd. As of now, my current directory is Desktop, and I have at least 10-15 `.c` files in my sub-directories under Desktop, but this command doesn't show any matches at all. So how do I make this work in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do:

```
grep -r "printf" *.c
```

the shell will expand `*.c` to all files/directories ending in `.c` in your current directory, if no such file/directory exists, the pattern will be treated literally (presumably you don't have `nullglob` set).

As you can see, your current pattern is  never going beneath the current directory as you don't have any `.c` file in the current directory or if there are any, they don't have `printf` in them, leading to the empty output.

You need to use `--include` to search in selective files only, and also `-r` to traverse recursively:

```
grep -r --include="*.c" "printf" .
```

The above will search in all `.c` files for the string (pattern) `printf`, recursively starting from the current directory.

if you want to follow all symlinks:

```
grep -R --include="*.c" "printf" .
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know why your command doesn't work,
see [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/823123/325633#823131). 
If you want to know how to make it work,
here's another approach <sub>(copied from
[Grep in files with a specific extension under a directory](https://superuser.com/q/1122124/354511#1122128)
with cosmetic localizations)</sub>
that uses the capabilities of `bash`
rather than the capabilities of `grep`
(and therefore will work for any command,
such as `wc`, `cp` or `tar`, and not just `grep`):

**S**et (turn on) the **sh**ell **opt**ion `globstar` with the command

```
shopt -s globstar
```

This will cause `**` as a filename component to mean
everything here and below. 
So, if you're in `Desktop`,
then `**` means everything in the `Desktop` directory
*and its subdirectories*. 
Then you can use

```
grep "printf" **/*.c
```

to search all the `.c` files in and under `Desktop`. 
You don't need to specify `-r`,
because the shell does the recursion for you,
and you don't need to specify `--include`,
because the pathname expansion pattern (a.k.a. glob or wildcard)
contains `*.c`.

---

You can **u**nset options with `shopt -u`.